# Ruby on Rails - User Devise Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having issues with routing with Devise and my `Users` model. I was trying to get `sign_out` to work and found an answer that suggested this.

// routes.rb

```
devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get '/users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create'
end
```

And while this works for signing out, if I use just that I cannot view a `User`.

`No route matches [GET] "/users/1"`

However, if I add back `resources :users`, I run into the first issue where `sign_out` or `sign_in` try to view a `User`.

`Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out`

How do I add `/users/index` to the `devise_for` loop?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try use `delete` instead of `get` on sign_out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `resources :users` after your `devise_for` block.

You can also use the following:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

Comment: I had `resources :users` before the `devise_for` block. Moving it after the block fixed my issue. Although, using the second suggestion doesn't seem to work, run in to he same issue as before.